# S3のオブジェクトとエンコード

Tags: aws, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

以下の順序でテキストファイルの整形をしています。

1. Lambda（node.js）からS3のテキストファイル（.deletes）を取得
2. Lambdaでテキストの中身を整形
3. 拡張子を.textに変更し、S3にput

3.でS3にputする際に 以下をputパラメータに持たせており、
putしたファイルをS3コンソール上で確認すると、メタデータにそれぞれが設定されていることが確認できました。

```
contentType = "text/plain";
contentEncoding = "UTF-8";
```

しかし、このファイルをダウンロードしてサクラエディタで確認すると、UTF-8ではなくSJISと表示されました。

どうすればUTF-8のファイルにすることができるのでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

元のテキストがSJISで書かれていて、lambdaないで特に文字コード変換を行なっていないなら、そのテキストはSJISのままです。
metaデータをいくら書き換えたところで、中身には影響しません。

Answer (score 0):

`iconv-lite` を使って文字コードを変換してはどうでしょうか。